# Why both my speaker only work when plugged directly into laptop?

Tags: audio, speakers, macbook-pro-retina

I have some [Logitech LS21 Speakers](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/ls21-2-1-stereo-speaker), when I plug them directly into my laptop (either a Lenovo or a mbp) both the speakers work; however, if I plug them into the subwoofer and then then I plug the subwoofer into my laptop (tested with both) then only the left works and not the right. I have tried adjust the sound from the left to right speakers when this is happening and when adjusting to the right the only thing that will happen is the left will get quieter and quieter but the right is still silent. How could I go about solving this problem? Thanks for for your help!

MBP (retina): el capitan 10.11.4

More specific info about problem:
When plugging the aux jack of the two speakers into my laptop (**note**: the two speakers are connected with one aux jack, see image) both speakers work. However when I plug the aux jack of the speakers into the subwoofer (see top left section of image) and then plug the auxiliary jack of the subwoofer into my laptop (**note**: there is an auxiliary cord coming out of the subwoofer, see image) only the left speaker works.

[image: speakers with one aux jack and subwoofer with one aux jack]

- The laptop's output works with and without headphones
- The subwoofers audio output works with headphones (see image)
- There are no mp3 players involved, only my laptop, headphones and the logitech speaker system (speakers and subwoofer)
- There are two cylindrical wires coming from each speaker and those wires feed into the single aux jack for the speakers

Comment: How do you plug two speakers that have separate cables (both intended to plug into the subwoofer module) into a laptop with only one headphone jack?

Comment: there are two aux cords. The speakers have one and the subwoofer has one. so: Speakers -> laptop (works) **but** speakers->subwoofer->laptop doesn't work

Comment: "Aux cord" means nothing. Any number of things can be called an "aux" (auxiliary). Your laptop has only one headphone/line out jack. So how do you plug two speakers into it at the same time? Does the laptop's output work ok with headphones? Do you have something else, like an MP3 player or a phone that can play stereo audio through its headset jack, that you can plug the subwoofer's cable into? Also: On the plugs attached to the speakers' cables, are there two different metallic sections with one insulating ring between them, or three metallic sections with two insulating rings?

Comment: hey jamie, please see edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned the MP3 player or phone because I wanted you to try it with a different source than your laptop. This was to be a troubleshooting step.

However, since you reported it works fine with headphones, *and* you have the same issue with a different laptop, we can be pretty confident that it's not the laptop. If the laptop emits correct sound to headphones it will do so with anything else.

And since the speakers work fine without the subwoofer box in the path, it isn't the speakers.

The problem is almost certainly somewhere in the rest of the setup: The cable from the subwoofer to laptop; the jack on the sub box that the speakers' plug plugs into; that volume control dongle, or inside the subwoofer box itself.

Sorry about this, but I doubt there is anything you can do to fix it unless you have a little bit of electronics tech competency: soldering, identification of wires, etc. And depending on how complex the subwoofer box is, the problem might be on the actual amplifier board inside, in which case it'll need a lot more competency. A lot of repair shops won't even touch it, because no schematics or other troubleshooting aids are normally available for this stuff.

So: If it's in the "free return" period from wherever you bought it, do that. Otherwise, if it's under warranty, return it to Logitech for repair. Failing that, investigate local repair shops.

(Terminology nitpick: Note, plugs are the things with pointy bits, jacks are the things with holes. If you had a hole in your boat, you'd want to *plug* it, right? Plugs fill holes... It isn't an "aux" anything, either. "Auxiliary" connections are normally for devices other than "the ones the device already has specific labels for.")

Comment: Terminology Nitpick. Your nitpick is **wrong**. The pointy thing is actually a jack or plug. A socket is the thing with holes. "a phone connector, also known as phone jack, audio jack or jack plug, is a common family of connector typically used for analog signals, primarily audio. It is cylindrical in shape, typically with two, three or four contacts. Three-contact versions are known as TRS connectors, where T stands for "tip", R stands for "ring" and S stands for "sleeve". Similarly, two- and four-contact versions are called TS and TRRS connectors respectively."

Comment: [What is the difference between a connector, jack, plug, socket, and port?](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001379.htm)

Comment: Look like "jack" has an ambiguous definition. It can be a plug **or** a socket :/

Comment: No, I'm not wrong. The people who claim it is correct to call a plug a jack are wrong. Clearly a plug is something that fills holes. I never in my life put a "jack" in the sink drain to stop it from draining.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29 "In electronics, a phone connector, also known as phone jack, audio jack or jack plug, is a common family of connector typically used for analog signals, primarily audio. It is cylindrical in shape, typically with two, three or four contacts. Three-contact versions are known as TRS connectors, where T stands for "tip", R stands for "ring" and S stands for "sleeve". Similarly, two- and four-contact versions are called TS and TRRS connectors respectively." seem to disagree with you.

Comment: It's a UK vs US thing: "In the UK, many Commonwealth countries and some non-English-speaking countries, the word "jack" may refer to the plug on the end of a removable cable. These connectors were originally referred to as "jack plugs", or plugs intended to be mated with fixed receptacles, or sockets (which North Americans would call "jacks"), but the second word was dropped. This variant usage is in direct contradiction to common usage and official standards in North America.

Comment: I'm quite aware of what the Wikipedia article says, having contributed to it. (I've also been assembling cables with these connectors for about 50 years.) Personally I maintain that calling a pointy thing that goes in a hole a "jack" as opposed to "plug" is _objectively_ wrong, for reasons I already gave. TRS, etc., do not contradict this; those terms merely account for the number of poles, and these terms are applied to both the plugs and the sockets. I will stick to this position no matter what quotes or standards you bring up, so further such from you will be pointless. ;)

Comment: See my previous comment - It's a UK vs US thing ;)

Comment: Yes, but in this case the Brits don't even have the utterly stupid excuse of "well, the French made us do it" the way they do with fly-in-the-face-of-what-few-rules-English-has abominations like "colour".

Comment: Now now, please behave. I'm a native English speaker, not a native American English speaker. Insults are unnecessary ;)

Comment: No insult intended. Just expressing the vehemence with which I hold, and will continue to hold, these positions.